# Set media query based on number of children using SASS

Tags: sass, media-queries

I have the following media query in SASS to create a responsive menu: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mL2vgo9/1/)

It works great, but I'd like to make the `@media` query change `max-width` property based on how many menu items there are, e.g. have something like this:

```sass
@function calculateWidth($element) {
    @return $element.width; // return actual width (if possible?)
    // or, return something like: 
    @return 50px * $element.children.length;
}

@media (max-width: calculateWidth('.vm-menu')){
  //.... whatever goes inside the query ....
}
```

is this possible with SASS alone? or maybe SASS/JS combination?

The reason I need this is that the number of items in the menu varies based on the permissions of the logged in user. So I could just set it to the maximum number of possible menu items, but it looks really awkward when the half-empty menu collapses for people who have 3-4 items displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think css can be aware of children elements, and sass compiles to css so it follows the same rules. It might be best to edit your html server side, or add classes with javascript. For example give the menu a class of .has-4-children and then write sass something like...

```
.menu
  &.has-4-children
    // Styles here
```